# Bitcoin node 403 json-rpc

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind

have read all possible examples on the internet but still cannot connect to btc node from Java.

I'm using btcd-cli4j but have tried all other rpc libs as well, result is the same.
This is the command:

```
BtcdClient client = new VerboseBtcdClientImpl(httpProvider, "127.0.0.1", 8332, "foo", "bar");
```

This is the docker image:

```
version: '3.3'

services:

bitcoind:
image: seegno/bitcoind:latest
command:
  -printtoconsole
  -regtest=1
  -rest
  -rpcallowip=172.18.0.2
  -rpcuser=foo
  -rpcpassword=bar
  -rpcport=8332
  -server
  -logips
  -debug=rpc
ports:
  - 8332:8332
```

Have tried couple of different docker images as well. Always the same:
Exception in thread "main"

```
HttpLayerException(super=CommunicationException 
(super=com.neemre.btcdcli4j.core.http.HttpLayerException: Error #1003001: The server responded with a non-OK (4xx) HTTP status code. Status line: HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden, code=1003001))
```

My suspicion was around rpcallowip but don't know how to set correctly. This one is set by going into the docker container and executing hostanme -i to see the ip address. Setting that one in config and restarting the container.

Comment: I suspect that you are actually connecting to the RPC service since you are getting a 403 status returned and not a timeout. Does it work if you remove `-rpcallowip=172.18.0.2`?

Comment: I would say that as well but cannot get a correct response. When removing it I'm getting Error #1004004: The operation failed due to an unknown IO exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add or changed to

```
rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0
```

this will fix most of rpc json 403 forbidden error (this has no security issues if your using it within your network)

Comment: I would have sworn I've tried this multiple times but heh, it is working now, that is all that matters :)