# can not access via RPC to litecoin node

Tags: json-rpc, litecoin, full-node, node.js

I set up a litecoin full node in AWS. I opened ports 22, 80 and 9332. Also from my laptop I cloned this project https://github.com/janoside/btc-rpc-explorer

I executed on my local but unfortunately I don't reached my litecoin node but instead if I deploy the btc-rpc-explorer in the same litecoin node it works.

The error I got when I executed in local is the following (IP have been obfuscated)

```
Unhandled Rejection at: Promise Promise {
  <rejected> { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9332
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1090:14)
  cause: 
   { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9332
       at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
       at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1090:14)
     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
     errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
     syscall: 'connect',
     address: 'XX.XXX.XXX.XXX',
     port: 9332 },
  isOperational: true,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: 'XX.XXX.XXX.XXX',
  port: 9332 } } reason: { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9332
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1090:14)
  cause: 
   { Error: connect ECONNREFUSED XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9332
       at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
       at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
       at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1090:14)
     code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
     errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
     syscall: 'connect',
     address: 'XX.XXX.XXX.XXX',
     port: 9332 },
  isOperational: true,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: 'XX.XXX.XXX.XXX',
  port: 9332 } stack: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED XX.XXX.XXX.XXX:9332
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1090:14)
Using exchange rate: 30.3812015012 USD/Litecoin starting at Sun Jan 13 2019 22:54:28 GMT+0100 (CET)
```

Do you know what I need to do to access the litecoin node from my local computer using this btc-rpc-explorer project? Thanks in advance

UPDATE: command netstat -tnlpu
Return this:
command netstat -tnlup
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
udp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*                           -
udp        0      0 172.26.6.153:68         0.0.0.0:*                           -

And in the AWS rules I have specified to let connections from ports: 22, 80, 9332. Any idea?

Comment: Is the node fully synced? If not, you should wait. Could you post here the listening ports on the node ? \# netstat -tnlpu

Answer (score 1):

I finally found how access the node from my laptop I just adding the following to the litecoin.conf file

rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0

I saw it in this [Answer](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/72524/91350)